# поучим я получаю ошибку Access-Control-Allow-Origin при ajax запросе

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest

делаю запрос с сервера `https://myhost.com`

```
    var settings = {
      "async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "https://get.auth0.com/oauth/token",
      "method": "POST",
      "headers": {
         "content-type": "application/json",
         'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,
         'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT',
         'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':"Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers",
  },
      "data": "{\"client_id\":\"fT05BFxl6\",\"client_secret\":\"Amla\",\"audience\":\"get.auth0.com/api/v2/\",\"grant_type\":\"client_credentials\"}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
```

еще побывал без `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,`

но ошибка та же

что означает эта ошибка , то-есть это API сервер не пропускает этот запрос или это сервер с которого я сделал запрос не хочет его принимать ?
и как все же получить `console.log(response);`

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://get.auth0.com/oauth/token' from origin 'https://myhost.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Comment: Крос доменные пост (и гет тоже, но там проще) запросы не разрешены в JS. Сервер на который вы отправляете запрос должен разрешить это в явном виде при помощи заголовков.

Comment: На чем крутиться сервер?

Comment: https://manage.auth0.com там api , а с которого запрос он на github pages. но я тестил разные связи и apache и nodejs все равно одно и то же